# How to create a program that asks user to enter "up to" 20 integers and uses parameter passing to functions to output the max, min, and average value?

Tags: c, arrays, function, parameter-passing

For an assignment I need create a program in C that uses arrays and functions and prompts the user to enter up to 20 integers to find the min, max, and average values. So far I have a program that works just fine when 20 numbers are entered by the user but entering less than 20 numbers makes this program print garbage values. I know there's a way to do this with malloc() but we havent learned that yet. What changes should I make so this program can handle less than 20 values? Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 20

int arrmin(int a[],int num_elements);
int arrmax(int a[], int num_elements);
float arraver(int a[],int num_elements);

int main(void)
{
   int a[SIZE],c,min,max;
   float avg;
   printf("Enter 20 numbers (q to quit)\n");
   for (c = 0; c <SIZE; c++)
   scanf("%d", &a[c]);


   max = arrmax(a,SIZE);
   printf("Maximum value is %d\n", max);

   min = arrmin(a,SIZE);
   printf("Minimum value is %d\n", min);

   avg = arraver(a,SIZE);
   printf("Average value is %f\n", avg);

   getch();
}

int arrmax(int a[], int num_elements)
{
   int i, max;
   max = a[0];
   for (i=1; i<num_elements; i++)
   {
      if (a[i]>max)
      {
         max=a[i];
      }
   }

   return(max);
}

int arrmin(int a[], int num_elements)
{
   int i, min;
   min = a[0];
   for (i=1; i<num_elements; i++)
   {
      if (a[i]<min)
      {
         min=a[i];
      }
   }

   return(min);
}

float arraver(int a[], int num_elements)
{
   int sum,i;
   float avg;
   sum=0;
   avg=0;

   for (i=0; i<num_elements;i++)
   {
      sum=sum+a[i];
      avg=(float)sum/(i+1);
   }
   return(avg);
}
```

Comment: How does the computer know the user is not going to enter any more numbers? You need to think about some delimiter like pressing the EOF key.

Comment: **Always** check the result of functions which might encounter an error - like `scanf`.

Comment: How does the user indicate _less_ than 20 numbers entered, vs. simply waiting for more?

Comment: Your code shows "q to quit". But your code as it is will not be able to catch that condition precisely because the `scanf` is looking only for integers. You can solve that in a number of ways, but let's assume that any non-number is considered to be the end of the input. In that case check that `scanf` return value is `1` for success. After that you just need to pass the actual number of inputs to the max/min/aver functions rather than `SIZE`. The count is already stored in the `c` variable, assuming you `break` when `scanf` fails.

Comment: Ok I think that's what I was doing wrong. I had this program set up so that q (or any non integer really) would end the program. I'll go ahead and try your suggestion thanks!

Comment: ....and it works! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your problem, i often use one of two ways:

- first way, you should input a number which is the size of your array at the beginning.  After that, you should allocate an array with this size and input elements.
- second way, you should input elements while element greater than 0. It mean, if you input a number 0, the inputing will stop. It not need input the size at the begining, and you can input elements everytime you want.